# how to determine time schedule run background fetch in swift

Tags: swift

I need to run a background fetch every day once at 2 pm

I have tried this :

this is my code running well as good , but work when ios opportunity to run background fetch

i am have selected setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval  in every day once but need to determine in clock 2 pm

how to use schedule with background fetch or determine time for run ??

```
application.setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval(86400) // set in func **didFinshLaunshingWithOption**
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, performFetchWithCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
       uploadJSON() { (newData,error) in
            if error != nil {
                NSLog("Failed")
                completionHandler(.failed)
            } else {
                NSLog("success")
                completionHandler(.newData)
            }
        }
    }
func uploadJSON(completion: ((Bool,Error?) -> Void )? = nil) {
        let data:String = "test sync"
        let session = URLSession.shared
        let request = NSURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "url")! asURL)
        let dataToUpload = data.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
        let uploadTask = session.uploadTask(with: request as URLRequest, from: dataToUpload,completionHandler: { (responseData, response, error) in
            // Check on some response headers (if it's HTTP)
            if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
                switch httpResponse.statusCode {
                case 200..<300:
                    print("Success")
                case 400..<500:
                    print("Request error")
                case 500..<600:
                    print("Server error")
                case let otherCode:
                    print("Other code: \(otherCode)")
                }
            }
            // Do something with the response data
            if let
                responseData = responseData,
                let responseString = String(data: responseData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) {
                print("Server Response:")
                print(responseString)
            }
            // Do something with the error
            if let error = error {
                print("Serverwwww Response:")
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                // completion?(false, error)
            }
        })
        uploadTask.resume()
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval` you can define only **how often** you need your app to update, but you need to remember that it doesn't provide deterministic behaviour. As described [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_environment/scenes/preparing_your_ui_to_run_in_the_background/updating_your_app_with_background_app_refresh):

> **The system waits until network and power conditions are good**, so you should be able to retrieve adequate amounts of data quickly

So with this API you let OS know that you would like to update your app e.g. every hour by calling `UIApplication.shared.setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval(3600)`.

With above in mind, you can set up that you need to perform an action every e.g. 10 minutes. Then every time when your code is executed, you just need to check what time is it and perform your background fetch as soon as possible after 2 pm.

Comment: Thank you, but are there other ways to automatically sync at a specific time

Comment: UIApplication.shared.setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval(TimeInterval(15*60)). TimeInterval takes time in seconds unit. Here, i call my periodic task in every 15  minute.